# Filter NSMutableArray with NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate

I fetch records from core data and fill `NSMutableArray` with them,now i want to filter them with below code but doesn't work properly.how should i do it?

```
[array filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date==%@",date1 ]];
//date = a field with format NSDate in core data
//date1 = NSDate
```

Comment: You're going to have to give us more than that; in what way are the results incorrect?

Comment: I check the results in array before do this filter and results is correct and after use this code no record exist in array ([array count]=0) although array should have 3 records

Comment: Obvious follow-up question — you're sure the dates are exactly equal? NSDate is precise at least down to the second and you're testing for exact equality. If you could show us an NSLog of your array before filtering and date1 that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because of that you enter date with time and when you want to filter array with `date1` the time of `date1` isn't equal to date that you store in core data

look at this code and enter a date without time

```
NSDate *dateTime=[NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                         fromDate:dateTime];
NSDate *dateOnly = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you use the predicate in your NSFetchRequest and keep the NSArray populated with only the records you need?

Comment: I did it and need to filter it again.

Comment: Change the predicate and fire off the Fetch Request again.